# SonarQube won't find every rule violations

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I'm using SonarQube 6.3.1 with default profile *Sonar way*. I have the newest SonarJava plugin installed (4.8.0.9441).

I can see that the rule **SQL binding mechanisms should be used** is activated.

[image]

I have installed SonarLint 2.9.0 plugin for Intellij and connected to running SonarQube server.

After copying example violation from Sonar page I can see in my IDE that plugin works fine. Everything seemed perfect up to this moment.

[image]

Unfortunately, analysis on SonarQube server doesn't find this vulnerability. The same goes for another owasp-a6 rule *Cookies should be secure* (also found by Sonarlint). But on the other hand, some owasp rules work (i.e. *Console logging should not be used*).
**Is this a known Sonar issue that some rules are omitted?** Exclusions are not a problem, I'm pretty sure that those files are being analyzed because some other issues have been found.

Comment: Can you specify the rule keys of the rules which do not work when performing external analysis, but work with SonarLint?

Comment: Sure, here there are: S2092, S2077, S3318. Also violation of S3271 wasn't deteced, neither by Sonar nor Sonarlint.